# Как создать Android виджет с настройками?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Мне нужно создать виджет с настройками. То есть на виджете должна быть кнопка, которая открывает окно с настройками. Как такое сделать?

Comment: 2000 рублей, а если серьезно, а что сделали вы?

Comment: Я спросил, как такое сделать, а не про цену.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы можете использовать [Configuration Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#UpdatingFromTheConfiguration). Здесь есть пример (в истории GitHub) простого виджета, который по нажатию на кнопку обновляет настройки: [TwitterWidget](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/b01438e7f0fed8f795ddec4be43066905f03d0cc/AppWidget/TwitterWidget).